# Issue with hdfs with java API

Tags: java, hadoop

I used following code to delete a file on hdfs filesystem

```
    conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
    // TODO: Change IP
    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://aaa.bbb.com:1234/user/hdfs");
    conf.set("hadoop.job.ugi", "hdfs");
    conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", 
        org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName()
    );
    conf.set("fs.file.impl",
        org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName()
    );
fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
fs.delete(new Path("/user/hdfs/file.copy"), true);
```

I created a user called "**xyz**" in my local machine, and to my amazement I was able to delete the file(**file.copy**) in hdfs filesystem with the given namenode whose owner was **xyz**. That means someone with the access to namenode url could delete anyfile by creating hdfs or root user?

I understand that Java API has a way to authenticate user using Kerberos, I believe solething is wrong with our configuration of the hadoop system. Could somebody help me to setup the security properly? I believe remote user should provide some key or key file to authenticate itself. Just same username won't do!

PS: I am using Cloudera 5.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you don't have Kerberos authentication enabled on your cluster then you really have no authentication at all. If you care about your data you absolutely should enable Kerberos authentication.